# Binding ItemsControl Items Property to outside Source Object

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, caliburn.micro

I have a List of objects of type *MenuModel* called *MenuList* inside my ViewModel. I am using CaliburnMicro framework

I would like to show this list as a list of ToggleButtons that have *IsChecked* property bound to other object list called *SelectedMenusMonday*, which is list of type *SelectedMenuModel* that has only IsSelected property and is the same length as MenuList.

MenuModel looks like this:

```
public class MenuModel
{
    public int MenuKey { get; set; }
    public string MenuName { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

MenuList:

```
public List<MenuModel> MenuList
{
    get { return _MenuList; }
    set => Set(ref _MenuList, value);
}
```

SelectedMenuModel

```
public class SelectedMenuModel
{
    public bool IsSelected { get; set; }
}
```

And SelectedMenusMonday list:

```
private BindableCollection<SelectedMenuModel> _SelectedMenusMonday = new BindableCollection<SelectedMenuModel>();

public BindableCollection<SelectedMenuModel> SelectedMenusMonday
{
    get { return _SelectedMenusMonday; }
    set => Set(ref _SelectedMenusMonday, value);
}
```

I am trying to display like this:

```
          <ItemsControl x:Name="MondayMenuList" ItemsSource="{Binding MenuList}" >
               <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                     <DataTemplate>
                         <ToggleButton Content="{Binding MenuName}" IsChecked="{Binding Path=DataContext.SelectedMenusMonday.IsSelected, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}">
                          </ToggleButton>
                      </DataTemplate>
                 </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
           </ItemsControl>
```

The MenuList and SelectedMenus Monday get filled from SQL DB. This is the solution i tried, but it does not work. Can someone help me please! I want the ToggleButtons to be "checked" if the item on the SelectedMenusMonday have IsSelected property as true.

Thank you very much!

Comment: you can check the output window for binding exceptions, or you can use third party apps such as snoop to delve binding exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

Name the root element in your view (or wherever you know the DataContext to be correct) and use `ElementName` binding as shown here:

```xml
<UserControl x:Name="view">
  <Grid>
    <ItemsControl x:Name="MondayMenuList" ItemsSource="{Binding MenuList}" >
       <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
         <DataTemplate>
           <ToggleButton Content="{Binding MenuName}" IsChecked="{Binding ElementName=view, Path=DataContext.SelectedMenusMonday}">
           </ToggleButton>
         </DataTemplate>
       </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
     </ItemsControl>
  </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Note the `x:Name="view"` in the `UserControl` element.

Comment: Thank you for the comment, but that did not help. Still all of the toggle buttons are unchecked. I also tried the with adding .IsSelected at the end of SelectedMenusMonday, but that did not do anything.